# How do I put a variable in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables

How do I put a variable in a string in JavaScript?

Example:

```
$('#contactForm').animate({"marginLeft": "+=680px"}, "slow");
```

I would like to use in a variable instead of `680px`, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most languages that don't have sigals, you can't perform interpolation, you have to concatenate multiple strings.

```
"foo" + "bar" + "baz"
"foo" + string_var + "baz"
"+=" + string_var + "px"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var size = "680px";
$('#contactForm').animate({"marginLeft": "+="+size}, "slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate your value in a variable to the `"+="` string:

```
$('#contactForm').animate({"marginLeft": "+=" + size}, "slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theWidth = "680px"
$('#contactForm').animate({marginLeft: "+=" + theWidth}, "slow");
```