# how to use the variable in a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a dataTable which I need to iterate through. so I have this code:

```
var tableSize = $('#j_idt11\\:dataTable tbody tr').length;
for(i = 0;i< tableSize;i++){
    var test1 = document.getElementById("j_idt11:dataTable:0:updFoodType").textContent;
    if(test1 == "food")
        alert("hey");
}
```

but I really want to use the i in the for loop. I thought something like this:

```
var tableSize = $('#j_idt11\\:dataTable tbody tr').length;
for(i = 0;i< tableSize;i++){
    var test1 = document.getElementById("j_idt11:dataTable:[i]:updFoodType").textContent;
     if(test1 == "food")
         alert("hey");
}
```

but that doesn't work. how must I use the syntax? Thanks!

Comment: It's easier for us to help you if your code is properly formatted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i put a variable in a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537981/how-do-i-put-a-variable-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: If you could write a better selector you could just use `$(..).each(fn)` .. and if using jQuery (or another magical `$` variant), it is sort of silly to mix in usages of `document.getElementById` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop has nothing to do with it, you need to concatenate the string,

```
for(var i = 0;i< tableSize;i++){
  var test1 = document.getElementById("j_idt11:dataTable:" + i + ":updFoodType").textContent;
  if(test1 == "food")
     alert("hey");
}
```

Also be careful with globals, you should declare `i` in the local scope as well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concatenate the value of i with your string:

```
var tableSize = $('#j_idt11\\:dataTable tbody tr').length;
for(i = 0;i< tableSize;i++)
{
   var test1 = document.getElementById("j_idt11:dataTable:" + i + ":updFoodType").textContent;
   if(test1 == "food")
      alert("hey");
}
```